# Изменить массив в PHP

Tags: php

есть массив
`Array ( [ИНН] => Array ( [1] => 7327087940 [2] => 7325101188 [3] => 5260220543 [4] =>` `5252036269[5] => 525716642276 [6] => 330573650180 ) [Телефон] => Array ( [1] => +78422360808` `[2] => +79053494773 [3] => +79524407252 [4] => +78317164180 [5] => - [6] => - )`

Только начал изучать PHP. Хочу получить такой массив, где ключ это ИНН
`array(7327087940 => ('ИНН' => 7327087940, 'Телефон' => +78422360808),` 
`7325101188 => ('ИНН' => 7325101188, 'Телефон' => +79053494773),`
`5260220543 => ('ИНН' => 5260220543, 'Телефон' => +79524407252)....`

Подскажите, как мне получить такой массив?

Answer (score 0):

Вам достаточно перебрать внутренний массив с ИНН и по номерам ключей сопоставить записи из них, например:

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($data['ИНН'] as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value] = [
        'ИНН' => $value,
        'Телефон' => $data['Телефон'][$key] ?? '-',
    ];
}

var_dump($result);
```